# Как запретить установку курсора в поле?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то запретить установку курсора в поле? Благодарю!

```html
<textarea name="text" id="text" onfocus="setFieldName(this.name)" rows="2" required></textarea>
```

Comment: Вы хотите просто что бы человек не мог продолжать писать в произвольном месте уже существующего текста?

Comment: `onfocus="this.blur();"` так чтоли ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[css - poiner-events:none](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) + [tabIndex="-1"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B/tabindex). Первое отменит события мыши на элементе, второе запретит переход на элемент через **`tab`**.

```css
#text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="text" id="text" tabIndex="-1" onfocus="setFieldName(this.name)" rows="2" required></textarea>
```